# System.Data.SQLite for .NET 4.6 in a project that targets .NET 4.7.2

Tags: .net, vb.net, system.data.sqlite

I am working on a VB .NET app that targets .NET 4.7.2.

I need to use System.Data.SQLite in my project. Currently, the SQLite folks only have precompiled binaries for .NET up to version 4.6.

I found a recommendation from the download page for System.Data.SQLite:

> Choosing the package matching the version of the .NET Framework being targeted is highly recommended.

You can see the dilemma. There is no package for .NET 4.7.2.

So, is it possible to reference System.Data.SQLite binary assembly for .NET 4.6, in a project that targets .NET 4.7.2? If so what are the potential implications?

Comment: There is no point for them to create a package for every minor framework update, 4.6 is fine.

Comment: Or maybe you could compile the library yourself ? See for example: [Building System.Data.SQLite from Source, Builds with Target Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8095500/6843158)

Comment: The 4.x versions of the .NET Framework are all built directly on top of .NET 4.0, meaning they are rather backwards compatible. In most cases you should be able to reference libraries built even for .NET 4.0 whilst targeting a higher version such as 4.7.2 or 4.8.

Comment: @HansPassant will it work if i install sqlite for .net framework 4.6 for my 4.7.2 project?

Comment: @HansPassant They have versions compiled for .NET 4.6, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4.0, and even older. I assume there is a point to having all these versions, though I can't seem to find an explanation as to why. Any chance you can expand on your comment and explain why using 4.6 is going to be fine?

Comment: @VisualVincent OK interesting, thank you for this insight. I'm going to do some testing and see how it goes.

Comment: @Rans Sorry for the very late reply, but as mine and Hans's comments explain: **Yes**, it will most likely work since all .NET 4.x releases are backwards compatible with earlier .NET 4.x code. For example if you target 4.7.2 you should be able to use libraries built for 4.7.1, 4.7, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5 and even 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply anyway, Yes it worked for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the answer is yes, you can use the .NET 4.6 version of System.Data.SQLite in a project that targets .NET 4.7.2.

I have arrived at this answer by taking on board comments made by HansPassant and VisualVincent, and extensive testing on my end via the C# project I've been working on which targets .NET 4.7.2 while using the System.Data.SQLite binary that targets .NET 4.6.

The reason why it works is because all releases of .NET 4.x use [CLR version 4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies). Microsoft does try to maintain [backwards compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility) so in most cases scenarios like this should present no issues at all.